# What's the difference between object file and static library(archive file)?

Tags: object, archive

Seems archive file can be generated from object file:

```
ar rvs libprofile.a profile.o
```

What's the difference between object file and archive file?

It seems to me that both can be used with gcc directly,e.g.:

`gcc *.c profile.o` or `gcc *.c libprofile.a`

What's the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why create a .a file from .o for static linking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852941/why-create-a-a-file-from-o-for-static-linking)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The static library is a collection of one or more object files, with an index to allow rapid searching. There are some minor differences in how the compiler deals with them. With an object file you link like this:

```
gcc f1.o f2.o -o myexe
```

with libraries you can also do that:

```
gcc f1.o libf2.a -o myexe
```

or you can use shorthand:

```
gcc d1.o -lf2 -L. -o myexe
```

Also, gcc will ALWAYS link .o files, but it will only search libraries and link from them if there are undefined names still to resolve.

Comment: Butterworth，but `gcc` can use them alternatively,or at least where .o is used,.a can also be used,right?

Comment: Yes, but as I point out, the usage can be slightly different.