# How to avoid mixing test and production code using GoogleTest?

Tags: c++, makefile, googletest

I am starting to use GoogleTest. It seems that it needs a main file for running the tests:

[Separate test cases across multiple files in google test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443970/separate-test-cases-across-multiple-files-in-google-test)

But currently in my demo application I already have a main file:

```
src/
-> MyType.h
-> main.cpp
-> Makefile
```

Which will eventually be my "production" application. I don't want to clutter that with gtest includes, macros etc.

Should I just create another main.cpp file in another folder e.g.: `test/` that will contain all the specific gtest configuration so I would end up with:

```
src/
-> MyType.h
-> main.cpp
-> Makefile // Makefile for producing production code/binaries
Test/
-> MyTypeTest.h // Unittest for MyType
-> main.cpp // The "Test runner"
-> Makefile // Makefile for producing test executable
```

**EDIT:**

Found this based on cmake:

http://www.kaizou.org/2014/11/gtest-cmake/

which seems to be exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: You might want to switch to a different build system before your project gets big. Makefiles tend to get really convoluted for bigger projects unless you already have much experience managing makefiles.

Comment: I tend to setup a tests subdirecty for each project/library, and generate a google test binary for each test source file. That way, even if one testcase causes an application crash, all other tests and testcases will still run. (I am using `CMake` as build tool and use `ctest` to run all tests)

Comment: I always liked the idea of the tests living in a separate directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most sensible approach to this is to have a library for your production code and then two executables, one for production and another one for tests:

```
|-lib/
| |-Makefile
| |-mytype.h
| `-mytype.cpp
|-app/
| |-Makefile
| `-main.cpp
`-test/
  |-Makefile
  `-mytypetest.cpp
```

Notice that gtest distribution provides the `gtest` library and a `gtest_main` library with the standard main function for your test executable. So unless you need a custom main (rare case) you don't need to provide a `main.cpp` for your tests and can simply link against `gtest_main`, e.g. `$(CC) mytypetest.cpp -o apptests -lapplib -lgtest_main -lgtest`.

The library approach involves slightly more complex `Makefile`s, but it pays off in compilation time, since not having it implies you need to compile `mytype.cpp` once for production application and once for test executable.

Comment: Yes it was something like that I had in mind, I found this: http://www.kaizou.org/2014/11/gtest-cmake/ that gives more details on a structure like you suggest using cmake. I will give that a try.

Comment: That's the source code structure I have for my current main C++ project. If you are planing to use cmake, you can benefit from its `ExternalProject` module to import the gtest libraries into your project. Find an example for this [here](https://github.com/apbarrero/cpp-utest/blob/master/test/CMakeLists.txt).

Comment: Cool gonna take a look at that! Btw what editor do you use? I would like to integrate with Git and be able to build/run with a single click/short-key so I tried eclipse but it does not really do what I want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668159/cmake-3-2-2-and-eclipse-4-5-1-cdt-8-0 Maybe I am a bit too ambitious here/need to go for a simpler/more manual approach?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of IDEs so I just use vim for small projects. I've been using QtCreator lately for a mid-size Qt project and it works quite well, it has a vim editor mode and there is a Google Test plugin. It is definitely more responsive and less cluttered then Eclipse CDT.

Comment: Just tried QT Creator as you suggested and it works like a charm, this is really great and I did not have any of the problems that I had with eclipse described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673956/function-expect-call-could-not-be-resolved-cmake-gtest-and-eclipse much better impression so far with QT Creator

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a lot of ways to do this, but generally speaking, yes, you should add a test-specific main function to your project. This makes compilation a little bit more complex since you'll have to produce two separate binaries (one for your application and another for your tests) but this is a fairly typical setup.

Comment: Ok makes sense, was thinking of creating just one makefile one level above the src/ and test/ folders and then put like a test and prod target in there, "make test" would create the test executable and "make prod" would create the prod executable is that against all conventions or reasonable?

Comment: That sounds reasonable, sure. Most Makefile projects I've worked with define separate targets for test and production executables. i.e. `make bin` will create the production binary, `make tests` will create the test executable, `make runtests` will run the tests, etc. Though, for anything larger than a toy project I'd suggest looking into CMake. It's a lot nicer than hand-editing Makefiles :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply add a test.cpp file with a main and create a `test` target in my makefile so that I could either `make` - to build my production code - or `make test` - to build the tests. In actual projects I use cmake in very similar fashion (I sometimes bundle all common dependencies in a `core.a` library and then link both main and test against it).